# Как загрузить информацию о конкретном пользователе из бд

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Как загрузить информацию о конкретном пользователе, который обращается к сайту и положить её в ассоциативный массив, например `$user_info`?

Comment: Я вас схематично в предыдущем сообщении написал. Посмотрите ради интереса документацию на mysqli. Хотя я бы рекомендовал перейти на PDO. Ваш вопрос слишком общий к тому же. Конкретизируйте

Comment: @ArchDemon Я пытался читать документация, но из-за того, что я прям новичок в php, я мало что понял. В предыдущем сообщении я не понял строку "// тут нужно добавить bind данных и исполнение запроса"

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php смотрите пример. И переходите уже на PDO. Там будет проще